# calling a stored procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm calling a stored procedure from php

```
<?php
include('global/db.php');
$id = 1;
$base = conn();
$query = "CALL get_id(:id,@userid)";
$stmt = $base->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetch());
?>
```

the stored procedure looks like this

```
BEGIN
SET @userid = (SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id = id);
SELECT @userid;
END
```

the procedure parameters

```
IN id int(10), OUT userid VARCHAR(255)
```

**Questions:**

- why does my result return nothing?
- what data type does my output variable `@userid` need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has some problems.

Since you have an output `userid`  why this `@userid`.

Also you are outputting `userid` , So there is no need to `SELECT` it

Another thing is, you can't select the entire row into a single variable, for multiple columns you should use multiple output variables.

```
BEGIN
    SET userid = (SELECT column_name FROM user WHERE user.id = id);
END
```

## Update

```
$result = $base->query("CALL get_id($id)");  
while($data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   echo $data['column_name'];
}
```

Comment: is there anyway for example to `SET somevariable = ` to say `SELECT division FROM user WHERE division = blah` where the result would return multiple `division1,division2,division3` aka scalar value `array`

Comment: did you mean multiple rows (matching the condition) ?

Comment: yea that exactly what I mean

Comment: yea I know that was wondering if it was possible in the procedure so that I could loop through the date within the same procedure.

Comment: yep, thats possible .

Comment: ok cool yea that's what I figured. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are defining a scalar parameter to entire query resultset as noted by asterisk. Consider using `INTO` clause to pass one query result value into the `OUT` parameter:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_id (
  IN  id int(10), 
  OUT userid VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SELECT user.id
  INTO userid
  FROM user
  WHERE user.id = id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And in PHP, you need to run a second query to return the `@userid` variable in a fetch command:

```
try {
    include('global/db.php');
    $id = 1;
    $base = conn();
    $query = "CALL get_id(:id,@userid)";
    $stmt = $base->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $base->query("SELECT @userid")->fetchAll();
    if ($result) { print_r($result); }

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    echo $pe->getMessage()."\n";        
}
```

Comment: so basically use can't use `*` since it will return an `array` or scalar value which you cannot set to variable?

Comment: Correct unless MySQL has an array/vector type. Do note, you can return full query resultsets without passing into an `OUT` variable.